# 3 beeps, pause, 3 beeps on boot

Tags: boot, hardware-failure

Since some time my PC gives (3 beeps, pause, 3 beeps, reboot) repeatedly on boot. Nothing on the screen.
Googling for this beep code gave me no meaningful results (it's certainly not a keyboard problem).
After many (around 30) tries of booting, it sometimes gets through and then I can use my PC for days (without powering down) without a problem. But once a few days my screens are black, keyboard lights frozen. After restarting my PC, I'm again faced with the boot issue.

My first though was that it is a GPU problem, as I could boot when I removed my GPU and used my motherboard video. However, that seems to have been a fluke.

Today removing the GPU didn't help as well and I started investigating further. I removed all devices attached to my PC. I unplugged all SATA cables (I don't have an M.2 SSD), removed my GPU, used a different PSU and removed 2 of the 3RAM sticks, changing which one of the 3 I used. I did a CMOS reset and used a new CMOS battery. I still couldn't boot, with the same beep code.

I plugged everything in again and started the boot loop. After about 20 minutes the PC finally booted successfuly. After confirming the UEFI default settings, and a rather long boot, Windows started without problems.

So... that's the current situation. I can use my PC but I'm afraid of rebooting it or powering down for any reason.

I guess it must be something related to the motherboard or CPU as I ruled out virtually everything else.

I can just buy a new motherboard and CPU (and probably RAM, because this one is still DDR3), but it would be nice to know what happened.

Any ideas?

My hardware:

```
Summary
    Operating System
        Windows 10 Home 64-bit
    CPU
        Intel Core i7 4770 @ 3.40GHz    41 °C
        Haswell 22nm Technology
    RAM
        24.0GB Dual-Channel DDR3 @ 790MHz (10-10-10-30)
    Motherboard
        ASRock H87M Pro4 (CPUSocket)    34 °C
    Graphics
        IPS235 (1920x1080@60Hz)
        D2343 (1920x1080@60Hz)
        DELL P2412H (1920x1080@60Hz)
        2047MB NVIDIA GeForce GTX 660 (ASUStek Computer Inc)    34 °C
    Storage
        232GB Samsung SSD 840 EVO 250GB (SATA (SSD))    31 °C
        931GB Seagate ST1000DM003-1ER162 (SATA )    29 °C
        931GB Samsung SSD 850 EVO 1TB (SATA (SSD))  30 °C
    Optical Drives
        No optical disk drives detected
    Audio
        NVIDIA Virtual Audio Device (Wave Extensible) (WDM)
```

Comment: Is this computer custom built or was it built by an OEM?

Comment: Get a manual for your motherboard and look up the beep code. Beep/error codes are different for every motherboard manufacturer because they are specific to a BIOS.

Comment: Are you sure the beep is a long beep instead of a short beep?  3 short beeps followed by a pause and another series of 3 short beeps is a memory problem.  If you had a faulty memory module, but it had not completely failed, what you describe makes sense.  I had memory fail in a machine that had not been turned on for a week.  So it’s happens; A new motherboard would be new memory and processor you would basically be building the entire system again since your using a legacy Intel socket

Comment: Given the symptoms you have, my suspicions are a problem with the motherboard itself. Possibly some traces that are conducting badly. By having the machine turned on for a long time, the temperature inside your case rises, which causes metal to expand which fixes the traces. May be a capacitor problem too. I would start looking into replacing the motherboard given all the tests you've done.

Comment: This is a custom built PC. It's 3 short beeps, pause, 3 short beeps.
The PC is always on (camera monitoring and other stuff). Letting it cooldown before booting may explain the behavior. I'll check the memory again just to be sure I don't buy a new motherboard and cpu for nothing.
@Ramhound, where do you find this description of this beep code?

Comment: I'll shut down the pc now, do some more tests with memory and check my exact BIOS version. Hopefully I don't have to use my phone to report back ;-)

Comment: @Coder14 - I searched for it.  I found dozens of results. Have you checked the manual for the motherboard?

Comment: I could boot after letting the boot loop run for a while. Nothing that seems useful for my case in the manual. I've tried again with each memory stick separatly. All failed to boot. So that seems to rule out memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*From the text dispersed here and there, I'd guess the culprit is on the motherboard, seems to work as the MoBo warms up a bit... so a broken PCB-trace, possibly. One might need quite advanced tools to find (=locate) the actual problem.*

One  step further, and a possible problem removal step:

- It isn't just the RAM modules: The RAM needs to have working communication via the databus and memory access/control lines (RW, CS, and all that), from RAM to CPU and vice versa.
- Use a pencil eraser - lightly - to erase the oxide (air oxygen induced "contamination") on the RAM module contacts.
- Get some "contact spray" from an electronics supplier (note: nothing else than that!) and spray it on the CPU-socket and RAM module connectors (on MoBo and modules)

... you might solve the problem by those two steps.

*I have removed strange effects on old computers by very similar methods. Old oxidized connectors will not allow current to flow as freely as required for correct function.*

Comment: Thanks, that sounds plausible. I might try that out later, but in the meantime I ordered a new motherboard, CPU and RAM. I need to be able to depend on my PC so I can't be sitting with fingers crossed hoping it will boot soon.